# Android code to switch between production and staging without using build varients using productFlavors in gradle

Tags: android

using following code in gradle we can switch between production and staging by changing in build variants tab.

```
 productFlavors {
    staging {
        applicationId = "co.example.staging";
    }
    production {
        applicationId = "co.example.production";
    }
}
```

I want a code to switch between production and staging in the beginning of application. With two radio buttons to switch between production and staging(using xml file). 
Is it possible to do like this?.

Comment: I don't think so. Considering the build.gradle is used to compile your application before it gets executed, I don't think you can have a radiobutton after the application has started to determine what version of the application to run.

Comment: @nbokmans is there any other way instead of changing in build.gradle

Comment: I can't say I've tried doing that, so I can't help you with that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

if you have debug option in staging. Check the debug flag using

```
boolean isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));

if (isDebuggable) {
// perform code for staging
} else {
// perform code for production.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u cant. once the application is packaged,its applicationId is decided;

Comment: Ok. But now what I am doing is manually changing the values in strings.xml file to change from production to staging and vise versa. Is there is way to use xml file to switch between staging and production?

Comment: what can u get from this change?

Comment: need to switch between production and staging with out modifying values in strings.xml

Comment: need to switch between production and staging with out modifying values in strings.xml?without?

Comment: Yes, Without hard coding to strings.xml file

Comment: why do u need hard coding to strings.xml ?what do the strings.xml use for?if u just want to use some test data . u can just add a value  in application store it .when its true ,u can use test data.otherwise ,u use normal data.add a longclick listion on a button to toggle it .the value is set false .

Comment: I used to store some URL.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
in application
String getPhotoUrl() {
   if(istest){
     retrun "http://"
    }else{
     retrun "192.168.15.89"
    }
 }
 boolean istest = false;
 in activity:
 btn.setOnClick(v->{

    istest = !istest;
    }     
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle file, you can have a staging buildType not necessarily a flavor.

```
    staging {
        initWith debug
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"internal.example.com"]
        applicationIdSuffix ".debugStaging"
    }
```

then you can check in code using

```
    if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == "staging") {
         ... do something...
    }
```

if you want to check flavor

```
   if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "staging") {
         ... do something...
    }
```